# Вход в ОС windows после некорректного удаления kali linux

Tags: windows-10, grub, kali-linux

Всем привет, в общем дело такое, я с помощью управления дисками в windows 10 полностью снёс kali, при перезапуске ноутбука grub выдал мне ошибку "error: no such partition". Я хочу загрузиться в windows 10. Это всё, что мне нужно. Я впервые оказываюсь в подобной ситуации, искал в Гугле решение данной проблемы, но либо я не зрячий, либо решений особо нет. Нужны ваши советы и помощь в целом. Буду благодарен любой помощи.

Comment: хороший вопрос - подписался

Comment: хотя я уже мильён раз это выеснял...без последствий если установленно если только два физических hdd или sdd ...в других случаях на самом деле только grub исправять ...а как это делать не знаю....точнее сколько раз но результатов  попыток 0

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Спасибо всем тем, кто хоть как то задумался над ответом, но не ответил. Я решил эту проблему достаточно просто. Я перепробовал множество вариантов  и ошибки все время менялись. Конечное решение было таким:
Я установил Ubuntu на флешку,при запуске от флешки есть два варианта - попробовать убунту без установки или же установить её рядом или вместо существующей ОС. Сначала я решил не устанавливать убунту полностью, а лишь "Попробовать её". Когда я загрузился - воспользовался Gparted, отделил кусок места от раздела с windows и установил убунту на этот кусок. В итоге граб пееустановился и остается лишь безопасно удалить убунту без потери граба. Да, возможно это решение ущербно, но в моей ситуации это помогло. Если есть вопросы - жду. Помогу,чем смогу)